# Unable to execute Cython wrapped Python code

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, shared-libraries, cython

I am exporting C++ API for python code using Cython. The application will be executed on Ubuntu. The project files are present [here](https://github.com/sanjaybharadwaj/Cython_Example.git)

The function I am wrapping, reads the file name of the image and displays the image. The `Show_Img.pyx` file looks as follows

```
import cv2

cdef public void Print_image(char* name):
  img = cv2.imread(name)
  cv2.imshow("Image", img)
  while(True):
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
```

The c++ interface generated from Cython looks as follows

```
__PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(void) Print_image(char *);
```

The header file is included in my `algo.cpp`, which calls the function like below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Python.h>
#include"Show_Img.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
  char *name = "face.jpg"; 
  Py_Initialize();
  Print_image(name);
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

With the command below, I can also compile the above code and also generate the application

```
g++ algo.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags python-2.7` `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -L. -lShow_Img -o algo
```

also the path to the library `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set correctly

Upon execution of the application, there is an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Why am I unable to execute the application, is there a mistake in the generation process? or Library linking?

Comment: You probably have to import the module. If you don't the stuff at the global scope (`import cv2`) won't get run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, You have to call an `init` function for the module:

```
// ...
Py_Initialize();
initShow_Img(); // for Python3
   // (especially with the more modern 2 phase module initialization)
   //  the process is a little more complicated - see the documentation
Print_image(name);
Py_Finalize();
// ...
```

The reason being is that this sets up the module, include executing the line `import cv2`. Without it things like accessing the module globals (to get to `cv2`) won't reliably work. This a likely cause of the segmentation fault.

This is in [the documentation example](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#public-declarations).

Comment: I tried importing the module cv2 inside the function, but still doesn't work, I added `import cv2` after the line `cdef public void Print_image(char* name):`

Comment: The key change is the addition of `initShow_Img()`. You _need_ to do this. It does a lot of things needed to make Cython work, beyond just `import cv2`.

Comment: Yes I realised it just now, that I had missed the statement. So dumb of me

Comment: No problem! Small additions aren't always obvious.

Comment: Hi David, I saw that you have worked extensively on Cython and Numpy tools. I am currently doing a student project that uses a lot of Cython, Is there anyother way I can contact you apart from StackOverflow?  I definitely believe that your answers will be of great help. Thank you in advance

Comment: I'd rather not I'm afraid. The numpy tag is pretty well used on stack overflow so you should be able to get good answers quickly. The Cython tag is a little slower but most reasonably questions do get answered. I think most questions would usually get answered a bit faster than this one (it's a slightly unusual use of Cython so fewer people will know the answer).